# istio: request by domain name between services return 404

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I got a namespace with istio auto-injection enabled, App-A and App-B are both in this namespace, App-A send post request to App-B to register itself, by using domain name "register.a.com". This domain name point to App-B's serivce ClusterIP(in my case is "10.79.229.193") through kubernetes "hostAliases". App-A always get 404 after sending request.

In App-A's pod, trying to send a post request to "register.a.com" using `curl` return 404, but by replacing this domain name with "10.79.229.193", it's all good.

It does has "Gateway" and "VirtualService" configuration, but those are for traffic from outside into the mesh, right?

Dose traffic between services in mesh naturally allowed? or I should configure about it?

Comment: Hi, what istio version do you use? It could be possible to use `ServiceEntry` to create internal alias that relies on dns resolution as described in [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/#ServiceEntry-Resolution).

Comment: @Piotr Malec Sorry for the delay, the version of Istio is 1.6.8, and I've read the docs you gave me, tried `ServiceEntry` in my deployment (as below), but it didn't work. I found that  `ServiceEntry` mostly use for "external service" that we'd like to manage by istio.

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: oa-register
spec:
  hosts:
  - register.a.com
  ports:
  - number: 8761
    name: oa-register
    protocol: HTTP
  location: MESH_INTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: 10.79.229.193

Comment: And I couldn't come up with what is the right configuration to achieve this.